# What happens in OpenGL 3.x+ if I don't specify a shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

I'm working with the new core OpenGL 4, so I'm using VAO exclusively and Vertex and Fragment Shaders.

But, What if I don't specify any shader at all, Does the system provide a default shader? e.g. a shader that draws a fragment with the current glColor and mvp?

Comment: What happened when you did not supply a shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a core profile, not providing shaders is prohibited.